# How do i make rails 3 model type cast according to migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, migration

The problem that i have is when i run my migrations the updates is applied to the database, but rails does not do the same.

To be more accurate. I have a address model with a house number. Recetly i was told that the house number should be able to contain letters, like (35B). Therefore i would like to convert the integer colum to a column of strings. This is no problem in any case with my data, red. only integers.

The migration that i applied works as expected. It changes the type of the column in the postgres database and preserves the data content. I was using this migration.

```
class ConvertIntToStringOnNumber < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :addresses do |t|
      t.change :number, :string
    end
  end
end
```

Migration result with this schema.rb

```
create_table "addresses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "street"
  t.string   "number"
  t.integer  "zip"
  t.string   "floor"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

After running the migration on my heroku server i am not able to query the database using data from the form, this was no problem before. Rails is trying to look for an integer, but the database is containing strings.

Rails is trying to run this query, even though the schema.rb says something different. This is where the party stops.

```
SELECT  "addresses".* FROM "addresses"  WHERE "addresses"."street" = 'xxxx' AND "addresses"."number" = 63 AND "addresses"."floor" = '' AND "addresses"."zip" = 9000 LIMIT 1):
```

I have seen a lot of problems with forigen keys, but this is NOT one of those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart your application after running the migration?

ActiveRecord loads information about your tables into each class when they are instantiated. See [#columns](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/columns) for more info. Since Heroku runs your app in production mode, your classes won't be automatically reloaded on each request.

Try running `heroku restart` on your application - Rails should pick up the changes then.